# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT when updated to Xcode 8.1

Tags: xcode, uipickerview, xcode8

I am getting an error that only appeared after I updated to Xcode 8.1. It appears in the AppDelegate.swift page on the line of

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

The error states “Thread 1: signal SIGABRT”. The app crashes when I try to segue from the initial screen to a second screen. On the second screen there is a picker view component and I am certain the error has to do with the initiation of that component, but no specific error is showing up on that ViewController page. The crash log states

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key PickerView.'".

(Note: ErrorTesting is just the name of the app right now because I created a short code just surrounding this specific issue to send to Apple Developer Technical Support if I cannot figure this out, but it really seems to be something I am just overlooking so ideally I don't want to use one of those credits right now.)

Here is the code of the View Controller that has the PickerView:

[Code overview of ViewController screen with PickerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2LL2.png)

Thank you in advance for your help. Any suggestions or advice would be much appreciated. I have already scoured the internet, but I cannot find any information on the PickerView configuration for this most recent update. Apple does have a sample code posted for PickerView in Xcode 8.1 (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/UICatalog/Listings/Swift_UIKitCatalog_PickerViewController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007710-Swift_UIKitCatalog_PickerViewController_swift-DontLinkElementID_73), but I still cannot figure out what is different about my code to theirs.

Comment: Don't post screenshots, post text.

Comment: In your ViewController in the Storyboard, you previously linked the IBOutlet to a UIPickerView named PickerView, and now it's named `Species_picker`, undo the link, and redo it to the new one. Also, don't start naming your var starting with an uppercase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: … this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v) One of the two top answers is your issue.